Does there exist a Haskell generalization of this two-pass scan algorithm that works for all two-pointer problems?
To make this question very precise and objective, I am looking for any nontrivial generalization other than "replace Int with some polymorphic numeric type".
In this old SO question, the following problem is posed:

You are given an input array whose each element represents the height of a line towers. The width of every tower is 1. It starts raining. How much water is collected between the towers?

This is a well-known basic programming exercise. You can find it on Google under the name Trapping Rain Water.
A very nice solution is given in the answers:
rainfall :: [Int] -> Int
rainfall xs = sum (zipWith (-) mins xs)
    where mins = zipWith min maxl maxr
          maxl = scanl1 max xs
          maxr = scanr1 max xs

And I would like to know if this can be generalized at all, preferably to (all) other two-pointer problems. I found this similar SO question, but I did not find the answers fully satisfying since they are specialized to the specific problem mentioned in the question.
In particular, I am looking for something with the same flavor as this generalized binary search implementation in Haskell or these generalized graph search algorithms in Haskell.

Perhaps you are looking for recursion schemes, especially histomorphisms.

Is the trapping rain water question even a two-pointer problem, whatever that is? The naive translation of zipWith to pointers involves two input pointers and one output pointer.

I agree it's not a formally-defined notion. I meant vaguely, "problems whose 'idiomatic' solutions in an imperative language use this strategy, although I suppose we are not returning indices in the OP, as you say. Indeed, it is partially because I am not sure how to precisely characterize this class of problems that I was interested finding such a generalization.

This elegant solution to the rain trapping problem uses the Tardis Monad, which lets you send state both forwards and backwards in the computation.
import Control.Monad.Tardis

levels hs = evalTardis (traverse 
  (\h -> do x <- min <$> getFuture <*> getPast -- Get the height of the enclosing walls
            modifyBackwards (`max` h)          -- Send the right max back to the past
            modifyForwards (`max` h)           -- Send the left max into the future
            pure (max 0 (x - h))               -- Calculate the height of the water itself
  ) hs) (0, 0)


sum $ levels [5,3,7,2,6,4,5,9,1,2]
14

See also this Reddit thread on real-world use of Tardis.
Combining TardisT with other monad transformers would be an interesting exercise.

Thanks, this is a very nice solution! Two follow ups: (1) what is the type of the generalized function here, and (2) what's the best we can do in a strict language (e.g. Idris)?

Also note that this does not have the same semantics as the zipWith version. This version gives nonzero volume for some lists of length 1, e.g. [-1]. How can it be modified to fix this?

@lanf You can always simulate laziness in strict functional languages using functions of type () -> a in place of values of type a, so it should be possible to implement Tardis(T) in Idris as well, though the API might be a little less convenient.

@PaulJohnson, I believe that for problems like finding the indices of two numbers in a sorted array with a given sum, the above solution will not work, although it is still a two-pointer problem. Both the zipWith and Tardis approaches force us to traverse from both sides at the same speed, do they not?

@lanf Hmm. I believe you are correct. The only way I can think of doing this is sending each value from the end of the list "back in time" in turn. But that is just tantamount to reversing the list. Answer updated.

To start, the trapping rainwater problem is not really a two-pointer problem. It involves two traversals in opposite directions, but they can be sequenced one after the other, whereas the distinguishing feature of two-pointer algorithms is that deciding which pointer to move is a core part of the logic.
Generic two-pointer algorithm
Here's my take on a generic two-pointer algorithm. The input consists of the following fields:

leftIter :: [l] is the list of values to be read by the left pointer (the list is used as an iterator, hence the name)
rightIter :: [r] is the list of values to be read by the right pointer
start :: s is the initial state
leftUpdate :: Maybe l -> s -> s updates the state with a value from the left pointer (or Nothing if the left pointer ran out of values)
rightUpdate idem with the right pointer
step :: s -> Step t asks the state whether to advance the left pointer, the right pointer, or halt with a result t.

Here the two pointers may read values of different types, although they are often the same in practice.
data Step c
    = NextLeft
    | NextRight
    | Done c

data TwoPointers l r s t = TwoPointers
    { leftIter :: [l]
    , rightIter :: [r]
    , start :: s
    , leftUpdate :: Maybe l -> s -> s
    , rightUpdate :: s -> Maybe r -> s
    , step :: s -> Step t
    }

Implementing the two-pointer algorithm using this data is straightforward.
headMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a
headMaybe [] = Nothing
headMaybe (x : _) = Just x

solve :: TwoPointers l r s t -> t
solve (TwoPointers { leftIter, leftUpdate, rightIter, rightUpdate, start, step })
    = go leftIter start rightIter
    where
        go !left state !right = case step state of
            NextLeft -> go (drop 1 left) (leftUpdate (headMaybe left) state) right
            NextRight -> go left (rightUpdate state (headMaybe right)) (drop 1 right)
            Done c -> c

One simple two-pointer problem is to find two numbers in a sorted list that sum to a target number. You need to stop when the pointers meet up (to avoid using the middle number twice if it equals target `div` 2), so each iterator (leftIter and rightIter) needs to produce the indices of the numbers in the original list. The state is simply the current pair of values (where the two pointers are pointing); we extract the ends of the input list as the initial state before we can set up the two-pointer algorithm.
The step function compares the sum with the target, and decides whether it found a solution, or whether to bump the left or right pointer.
-- Input: a target number and a sorted list.
-- Output: two elements of the sorted list whose sum equals the target.
findSum :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
findSum target xs =
    let ixs = zip [0 ..] xs in
    case (ixs, reverse ixs) of
        (l0 : lIter, r0 : rIter) -> solve (TwoPointers
            { leftIter = lIter
            , leftUpdate = \l (_, r) -> (l, r)
            , rightIter = rIter
            , rightUpdate = \(l, _) r -> (l, r)
            , start = (Just l0, Just r0)
            , step = \lr -> case lr of
                (Just (li, lx), Just (ri, rx)) | li < ri ->
                    case compare (lx + rx) target of
                        EQ -> Done (Just (lx, rx))
                        LT -> NextLeft
                        GT -> NextRight
                _ -> Done Nothing
            })
        _ -> Nothing

exampleFindSum :: Maybe (Int, Int)
exampleFindSum = findSum 14 [1,3,5,8,9,12]  -- 14 = 5 + 9

The above example has the two pointers walk through the list in opposite direction. Another standard example where they walk in the same direction is the longest bounded sum problem. The two pointers delimit a candidate sum. In this implementation, the state remembers the longest length seen so far, the length of the current sum, the value of the current sum, and a boolean flag to stop which is set when we reach the end of the input.
In the step function, if the sum is smaller than the bound, we try to add another element by advancing the right pointer; if the sum is greater than the bound, we remove an element by advancing the left pointer.
-- Input: a bound and a list of numbers >= 0.
-- Output: the length of the longest consecutive sum <= bound.
longestBoundedSum :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
longestBoundedSum bound xs = solve (TwoPointers
    { leftIter = xs
    , rightIter = xs
    , start = (0, 0, 0, False) -- (maxLength, curLength, curSum, stop)
    , leftUpdate = \l (maxLength, curLength, curSum, _) -> case l of
        Nothing -> (maxLength, curLength, curSum, True)  -- should not happen
        Just lx ->
            let newMaxLength = updateMaxLength maxLength (curLength - 1) (curSum - lx) in
            (newMaxLength, curLength - 1, curSum - lx, False)
    , rightUpdate = \(maxLength, curLength, curSum, _) r -> case r of
        Nothing -> (maxLength, curLength, curSum, True)  -- reached the end
        Just rx ->
            let newMaxLength = updateMaxLength maxLength (curLength + 1) (curSum + rx) in
            (newMaxLength, curLength + 1, curSum + rx, False)
    , step = \(maxLength, curLength, curSum, stop) ->
        if stop then Done maxLength
        else if curSum <= bound then NextRight
        else NextLeft
    })
    where
        updateMaxLength maxLength newLength newSum =
            if newSum <= bound then max maxLength newLength
            else maxLength

exampleLongestBoundedSum :: Int
exampleLongestBoundedSum  =
   longestBoundedSum 4 [3,2,3,1,0,1,2,3,2,1]  -- length [1,0,1,2] = 4

Two traversals
The "trapping rain water" problem really boils down to two traversals in opposite directions.
The "nice" solution in your question does it in more passes so that each pass can be described concisely as a zip or scan of a standard library function, but all of the passes after and including the second one can be fused together.
Here is a generic "two-traversal" algorithm. We first scan the input list left-to-right, accumulating values using bNext, and then we walk right-to-left using cNext, going through the accumulated values from the first pass.
twoTraversals :: [a] -> b -> (b -> a -> b) -> c -> (b -> c -> c) -> c
twoTraversals xs b bNext c cNext =
    foldr cNext c (drop 1 (scanl bNext b xs))

Of course, you can do two traversals with two pointers, i.e., implement twoTraversals using the two-pointer algorithm solve. The algorithm runs in two phases: the state starts out as a Left value, and we advance the left pointer; when we reach the end, the state flips to a Right value, and we advance the right pointer.
While technically two traversals can be done with two pointers, it does not make use of the pointers in any way as interesting as other typical two-pointer problems: the step function just "maps left to left, right to right".
twoTraversalsWithTwoPointers
    :: [a] -> b -> (b -> a -> b) -> c -> (b -> c -> c) -> c
twoTraversalsWithTwoPointers xs b0 bNext c0 cNext = solve (TwoPointers
    { leftIter = xs
    , rightIter = replicate (length xs) ()
    , start = Left (b0, [])
    , leftUpdate = \l s -> case (l, s) of
        (Just lx, Left (b, acc)) -> let !b' = bNext b lx in Left (b', b' : acc)
        (Nothing, Left (_, acc)) -> Right (c0, acc)
        (_, Right _) -> s -- should not happen
    , rightUpdate = \s _ -> case s of
        Left _ -> s -- should not happen
        Right (c, b : bs) -> let !c' = cNext b c in Right (c', bs)
        Right (c, []) -> s -- should not happen
    , step = \s -> case s of
        Left _ -> NextLeft
        Right (_, _ : _) -> NextRight
        Right (c, []) -> Done c
    })

As a bonus, you can technically implement twoTraversal using a single fold. The trick is that the accumulator is a function, which represents a roundtrip traversal from somewhere in the middle of the list to the right end, and back to where it started. Thus you can extend this function element-wise, by adding some processing before and after the accumulated function to produce a round trip that goes through one more element of the list.
twoTraversalsInOneFold
    :: [a] -> b -> (b -> a -> b) -> c -> (b -> c -> c) -> c
twoTraversalsInOneFold xs b0 bNext c0 cNext = foldr step (\_ -> c0) xs b0
    where
        step a k b =
            let b' = bNext b a in  -- forward traversal of current element a
            let c = k b'           -- k does the forward traversal through the rest of the list, and comes back with the backward traversal
            cNext b' c             -- backward traversal of intermediate value b' at the current position

These three implementations of a generic two-traversals algorithm are equivalent.
We can use any one to solve the trapping rain water problem.
In the first traversal, we also remember the current element which is discarded otherwise (we could also have written twoTraversal so that the second traversal receives the input values). In the second traversal, we accumulate both the maximum level from the right end and the total amount of trapped rainwater, which can indeed be computed together once the result of the first traversal is available.
-- Rain water problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water/description/
-- Input: A list of levels >= 0.
-- Output: The amount of rain water that this landscape can trap.
trappingRainWater :: [Int] -> Int
trappingRainWater xs = fst $ twoTraversalsWithTwoPointers
    xs
    (0, 0)
    (\(_, leftLevel) x -> (x, max leftLevel x))
    (0, 0)
    (\(x, levelLeft) (total, rightLevel) ->
        let levelRight = max x rightLevel in
        let level = min levelLeft levelRight in
        let water = level - x in
        (total + water, levelRight))

exampleTrappingRainWater :: Int
exampleTrappingRainWater = trappingRainWater [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,1] -- 6

A couple of unit tests below.
shouldBe :: (Eq a, Show a) => a -> a -> IO ()
shouldBe actual expected =
    if actual == expected then pure ()
    else error (show actual ++ " /= " ++ show expected)

testTraversal
    :: (forall a b c. [a] -> b -> (b -> a -> b) -> c -> (b -> c -> c) -> c) ->
       IO ()
testTraversal trav =
    let t = trav [1,2,3] 0 (+) [] (:) in
    t `shouldBe` [1,3,6]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    testTraversal twoTraversals
    testTraversal twoTraversalsWithTwoPointers
    testTraversal twoTraversalsInOneFold
    exampleFindSum `shouldBe` Just (5,9)
    exampleLongestBoundedSum `shouldBe` 4
    exampleTrappingRainWater `shouldBe` 6


Does your longest bounded sum problem require that the integers be nonnegative?

Mine does require it. Do you have one where that's not the case?

No, just making sure I understood.

I am posting a partial answer in the hopes that someone will be able to help me refine it. I used @Li-yao Xia's work to come up with the following function which avoids the use of an auxiliary data type.
data Step = L | R | Stop deriving (Eq, Show)

twoptr :: (a -> b -> b) -> (a -> b -> b) -> (b -> Step) -> (b -> c) -> [a] -> [a] -> b -> c
twoptr left right step finish = go
  where
    go []     []     b = finish b
    go (l:ls) []     b = go ls [] (left  l b)
    go []     (r:rs) b = go [] rs (right r b)
    go (l:ls) (r:rs) b =
      case step b of
        L    -> go ls (r:rs) (left  l b)
        R    -> go (l:ls) rs (right r b)
        Stop -> finish b

I was able to implement his findSum and LongestBoundedSum examples with it:
type Assoc = (Int, Int)

findSum' :: Int -> [Assoc] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
findSum' _      []      = Nothing
findSum' target (ll:ls) = twoptr left right step finish ls rs (ll,rr)
  where
    rr = NE.last              $ ll :| ls
    rs = NE.tail . NE.reverse $ ll :| ls
    left  l (_,r) = (l,r)
    right r (l,_) = (l,r)
    step ((li, l), (ri, r))
      | li >= ri       = Stop
      | l + r < target = L
      | l + r > target = R
      | otherwise      = Stop
    finish ((li, l), (ri, r))
      | li < ri   = Just (l, r)
      | otherwise = Nothing

findSum :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
findSum target xs = findSum' target (zip [0..] xs)

exampleFindSum :: Maybe (Int, Int)
exampleFindSum = findSum 14 [1,3,5,8,9,12]

data State = State Int Int Int deriving (Eq, Show)

lbs :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
lbs bound xs = twoptr left right step finish xs xs (State 0 0 0)
  where
    left  x (State lmax l csum) = State lmax         (l-1) (csum-x)
    right x (State lmax l csum) = State (max lmax l) (l+1) (csum+x)
    step (State _ _ csum)
      | csum > bound = L
      | otherwise    = R
    finish (State lmax _ _) = lmax

exampleLongestBoundedSum :: Int
exampleLongestBoundedSum = lbs 4 [3,2,3,1,0,1,2,3,2,1]

However I couldn't figure out how to apply it to the rain water problem. And in any case when you need indices/locations, this template still makes it pretty easy to mess things up. So I'm not quite satisfied.
I am inclined to believe that you'd only want to resort to such a generalization when the problem requires you to return indices, and otherwise it's better to write something that's "coordinate-free", like the following shorter version of longestBoundedSum:
-- | Length of longest contiguous subarray with sum <= bound.
longestBoundedSum :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
longestBoundedSum bound = longest . filter bounded . subarrays
  where
    longest   = foldr (max . length) 0
    bounded   = (<= bound) . sum
    subarrays = inits <=< tails

So this suggests that it would be useful to write a version of twoptr with the index information already baked-in. But I'm not sure how to do that.
